# D3 Hierarchical JSON Trees without "name" attribute

Tags: json, d3.js, tree, visualization

In d3.v5, following hierarchical JSON can be used to create tree.

```
{
  "name": "Top Level",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Level 2: A",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Son of A",
        },
        {
          "name": "Daughter of A",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Level 2: B",
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to replace "name" attribute without some other attribute, say, "key"?

"children" function can be overridden and can be customized. Similarly, is it possible to do the same for "name"?

Comment: `name` is nowhere used in `d3.hierarchy`, so you can use what ever you want

Comment: "name" seems to be the default just like d.children is default. All examples use "name", "parent" or "name", "children". https://devdocs.io/d3~5/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy

Comment: where is "name" used? Only with `d3.stratify` but that has an accessor.

Comment: I think so because there is no clear explanation in the docs or other places. When I replace "name" with another attribute, it doesn't work. That's why my question or the question is basically about the internal representation of the tree node in d3.v5.